# Radio button array name - how to access them

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I have form with radio buttons that are array. I need to check if radio button is clicked, but I have problem with name. I tried to write it `answer` and `answer[]` but it doesn't show me the next question. If I write it `input[type='radio']:checked` iow can I do that? :)

```js
$(function () {
        $("#next").click(showNextQuestion);
    });

var currentInd = 0;
var prevInd = 0;
function showNextQuestion(){
$(function () {
 var indId = "#"+currentInd;
 prevInd = currentInd - 1;
 var prevId = "#"+prevInd;
 //validation
 var isAnyClicked = false;
 

 if ($("input[name^='answer']:checked").val()) {
     isAnyClicked = true;
 }
 if(currentInd > 0 && isAnyClicked == false)
 {
  alert('Otgowori!');
 }
 else{
  //hide previous question
  
  $(prevId).hide();
  
  //show next question 
  var indId = "#"+currentInd;
         $(indId).show();
         currentInd++;
    }
    });
}
```

```html
$data=array(
   'name' =>  'answer['.$row->question_id.']',
   'value' => '5'
  );
echo form_radio($data); 
  echo " 5 ";
  $data=array(
   'name' =>  'answer['.$row->question_id.']',
   'value' => '4'
  );
  echo form_radio($data);
  echo " 4 ";
  $data=array(
   'name' => 'answer['.$row->question_id.']',
   'value' => '3'
   
  );
  echo form_radio($data);
  echo " 3 ";
```

Answer (score 1):

since you have the ids inside like this: answer[xxx] I'm not sure your selector will work.

you might try this which finds an attribute that starts with a value (in your case something like:

```
input[name^='answer']:checked
```

though I haven't tested it.

https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Comment: Yes, it works, but only for the first question. I push next but the other questions have no validation. It's for the first only.

Comment: where are you getting "currentInd" from?

Comment: and currentInd relates to $row->question_id?

Comment: Yes - for  current question.

Comment: well then you can do this: "input[name='answer[" + currentInd + "]']:checked" and I think it will grab the one you've clicked on. As to why it isn't showing your next one - it is hard to say, but I don't see anyplace you're increasing the value of currentInd... don't you need to do that to show the next one?

Comment: I increased it - currentInd++; in the end of JS code.

Comment: put *currentInd++* before *var indId = "#"+currentInd;* Just as a test?

Comment: No, it doesn't show me the first question at all. Only Next button.

Comment: :( sorry. I'm not sure then.